# How to replace deprecated saveOrUpdate() method in Hibernate 6?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-6.x

With Hibernate 6.0 the `saveOrUpdate(entity)` method is now deprecated. The Javadoc suggests to replace it with either `merge()` or `persist()`.

But doing so breaks some of my tests with "A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session" (merge) or "Unique index or primary key violation" (persist).

How do I properly replace my `saveOrUpdate()` calls?

Comment: You can't just rename saveOrUpdate to merge or persist. A minor code change is needed. Load the entity from the database. Use merge if existent. Use persist if not.

Comment: Or even better: use JPA repository save method instead of vanilla Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the first one is what I feared, the second one sounds interesting (although currently only have an `org.hibernate.Session`). Could/Would you poste it/both(?) as a (full) answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out (thanks for the hint, Mar-Z!).

```
if (Objects.isNull(session.find(MyEntity.class, entity.getId()))) {
    session.persist(entity);
} else {
    session.merge(entity);
}
```

This starts by loading the entity from the database by its ID and checks if it is returned. If nothing is returned `persist()` inserts it as a new entity into the database, otherways the existing entry gets updated by `merge()`.

Answer (score 0):

> But doing so breaks some of my tests with "A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session" (merge)

This is at least *somewhat* unexpected, since this error doesn't usually occur from `merge()`.

But you would need to post (simplified) code and **most importantly a stack trace** to have any hope of us being to able to help you resolve it.

> or "Unique index or primary key violation" (persist).

This sounds normal.

> How do I properly replace my `saveOrUpdate()` calls?

Ordinarily, you would replace it with a call to `merge()`. But note that `merge()` does have different semantics, so it's certainly not a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using such solution:

```
public void saveOrUpdate(Object entity) {
    if (this.entityManager.contains(entity)) {
        this.entityManager.merge(entity);
    } else {
        SessionImplementor sessionImplementor = entityManager.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class);
        EntityState state = EntityState.getEntityState(entity, null, null, sessionImplementor, true);
        if (state == EntityState.DETACHED) {
            this.entityManager.merge(entity);
        } else {
            this.entityManager.persist(entity);
        }
    }
}
```